# nslayoutconstraint animations different delays

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

Hello I've search all over the internet, but can't find anything.

For example. I have 2 views, lets say view1 and view2. Both have topConstraint properties.

I can animate them easily by setting:

```
view1.topConstraint.constant = 50;
view2.topConstraint.constant = 250;

[self.scrollView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
        [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Is there a way to animate NSLayoutConstraints with different delay?
E.g I want to do it like this

```
view1.topConstraint.constant = 50;
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

view2.topConstraint.constant = 250;
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f delay:2.0f options:0 animations:^{
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: What result do you see with the code you posted?

Comment: @rdelmar all the animations finish and starts at the same time, I want them to start and finish at different times.

Comment: I tried similar code, and it worked fine for me. The difference in what I did, was that the constraints that I was animating belonged to the superview (Self.view of the controller) not to the subviews.

Comment: @Lukas, have you found a workaround for this?